# Mocking a method to assign value to field in Model C# Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I need to add a method to a model that given some parameters assigns a value to one of the model's fields.

```
public class ModelName: SomeModel<ModelName>, IModelName
{
    [Field]
    public string SomeField{ get; set; }

    [Field]
    public string FieldSetByMethod{ get; set; }

    public new async Task MethodToSetField(string parameter)
    {
        var someClassInstance = new SomeExternalClass(parameter);
        FieldSetByMethod = someClassInstance(parameter).method();
    }
}
```

Now when I'm writing unit tests and I want to have a way of checking that this `MethodToSetField` was called. However, I can't really actually call the `MethodToSetField` method as creating `SomeExternalClass` is not desirable (e.g. because it creates unique ID).

I don't really have experience with neither C# nor Moq. How can I mock this function so it behaves more or less like this:

```
ModelNameInstance.Setup(c => c.MethodToSetField("Parameter")).Assigns(FieldSetByMethod,"DummyValue");
```

Or maybe I can somehow restructure the code / write tests in a way to imitate this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You could inject `ISomeExternalClass` into this class and then mock it, and test against the mock, or if you can't do that - inject `ISomeExternalClassFactory` into this class and then mock it. `ISomeExternalClassFactory` mock would return a mock of `ISomeExternalClass` that you could setup and test against.